# Access SQL - If TotalPrice is > 30, Discount = 30%

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm working on an access database at the moment, where I have multiple fields.

- Product Quantity (Entered by User)
- Product Price (Retrieved by Database)
- Total Price (Product Quantity * Product Price)
- Discount

[image]

Discount needs to be calculated, however I don't know how to set it to 30% on the condition that TotalPrice is more than 50. It would be useful if the TotalPrice automatically updated if it was more than 50 with the discount too.

Comment: Do you have any code to share? Otherwise I fear your question will be placed on hold

Comment: There is no code, I'll share an image and some other information.

Comment: [link]http://imgur.com/p6wp7mC[link] - Here is the database itself. There is no code, I need help to set the discount to 30% if TotalPrice is > 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a new query that brings in Product Quantity, ProductPrice and TotalPrice.  Then, in the Design View of the query, add this field:

```
Discount: IIF((ProductQuantity * ProductPrice) > 50, 30, 0)
```

If you're not familiar with IIF statements, the above reads: "If ProductQuantity times ProductPrice is greater than 50, then set Discount = 30, otherwise set Discount = 0"

This will set your discount = 0 if Total Price is less than or equal to 50, so edit that last part if it needs to be something else.  Also, I made assumptions on your field names, so you may need to tweak those too, but you get the idea.

If you need Discount to actually reflect 30% of Total Price, then if would look like this:

```
Discount: IIF((ProductQuantity * ProductPrice) > 50, (ProductQuantity * ProductPrice) * .30, 0)
```

Comment: So I would just use a SELECT statement to select the fields, and where would I put this statement?

Comment: SELECT OrderDetailsT.SandwichQuantity, OrderDetailsT.SandwichPrice, OrderDetailsT.Discount
FROM OrderDetailsT
WHERE (((OrderDetailsT.Discount)=IIf(("SandwichQuantity * SandwichPrice")>50,30,0)));

Comment: SELECT OrderDetailsT.SandwichQuantity, OrderDetailsT.SandwichPrice, IIf((SandwichQuantity * SandwichPrice)>50,30,0) as Discount FROM OrderDetailsT WHERE (SandwichQuantity * SandwichPrice)>50;

Comment: Another odd thing, it doesn't update the record in the OrderDetailsT. It only does it when I use the query, so by default the discount is whatever the customer enters. 

[link]http://cl.ly/T21b[link]

Comment: You would need to use an Update query if you wanted to make the changes permanent.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a data entry screen You can add an `After_Update` Event to `Sandwich Price` And `Sandwich Quantity`

```
Private Sub SandwichPrice_AfterUpdate()
   update_total 
End Sub

Private Sub SandwichQuantity_AfterUpdate()
   update_total 
End Sub
Private Sub update_total()
   Dim total AS Double
   If IsNull(Me.SandwichPrice) OR IsNull(Me.SandwichQuantity) Then Exit Sub
   total = Me.SandwichPrice * Me.SandwichQuantity
   SELECT CASE total
       CASE 51 to 1000
          Me.Discount = 0.3
       CASE Else
          Me.Discount = 0
   END SELECT
   Me.TotalPrice = total - (total * Me.Discount)
End Sub
```

Doing it this way will allow you to add multiple tiers of discount by adding `CASE` Statements i.e. You could add `CASE 10 TO 20` with a new discount and it will apply when `TotalPrice` is `>=10 And <= 20`.

This will allow your lookup query to return the correct values from discount. I don't think this should be handled in the lookup query but rather in the data storage itself.

Comment: Where would I implement this? I'm not familiar with VB.

Comment: On the entry form open in Design view Right click on SandwichQuantity TextBox -> Properties. In the Properties Window goto the Event Tab Click on the AfterUpdate field -> CodeBuilder repeat for SandwichPrice. Paste update_total on the same screen